# Proper header to download a PDF from Liferay webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview, liferay-6

I have to download a PDF in a liferay portlet loaded in an andoid app using a webview.

The header I set in Liferay is:

```
res.setContentType("application/pdf");
res.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment; filename=" + cod+ "");
res.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL,"max-age=3600, must-revalidate");
```

What happens in the app is that the request is sent, the PDF in generated in Liferay server, but when receiving the PDF in the app, nothing happen. I need that this PDF is downloaded in the app.

Any help?

Comment: What type is `res`? What's the method this code is in?

Comment: res is a javax.portlet.ResourceResponse and the method is "serveResource" in a Liferay portlet

Comment: Could you add some details about how the file is downloaded. In your webview, there is a <a> Link referencing the serverResource portlet call? Maybe add a `download` attribute ([w3Schools download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)) to your hyperlink. Can you verify the headers are set when debugging the call with your browser web tools?